# Not able to create a map with generic class as key and a list of generic type objects as value

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to construct a hashmap of class (key) to the list of tasks (value) for that particular class. Here's my code:

```
public class StaticTaskListProvider<TEntity extends ScannableEntity> {

    private final Class<TEntity> entityType;
    private static Map<Class<? extends ScannableEntity>, List<Task<? extends ScannableEntity>>> entityToTaskListMap;

    public StaticTaskListProvider(Class<TEntity> entityType) {
        this.entityType = entityType;
        initializeMap();
    }

    private void initializeMap() {
        entityToTaskListMap = new HashMap<>();
        entityToTaskListMap.put(EntityA.class, entityATaskList());
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }

    private List<Task<EntityA>> entityATaskList() {
        List<Task<EntityA>> entityATaskList = new ArrayList<>();
        entityATaskList.add(new NewTask());
        return entityATaskList;
    }
```

But I am getting the following error while trying to add the `List<Task<EntityA>` to the map even though the `EntityA extends ScannableEntity`.

```
 error: incompatible types: List<Task<EntityA>> cannot be converted to List<Task<? extends ScannableEntity>>
        entityToTaskListMap.put(EntityA.class, entityATaskList());
                                                             ^
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you:

```
private List<Task<? extends ScannableEntity>> entityATaskList() {
    List<Task<? extends ScannableEntity>> entityATaskList = new ArrayList<>();
    entityATaskList.add(new NewTask());
    return entityATaskList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

quote from [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html)

> Given the following two regular (non-generic) classes:
>
> ```
> class A { /* ... */ } 
> class B extends A { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> It would be
> reasonable to write the following code:
>
> ```
> B b = new B(); 
> A a = b;
> ```
>
> This example shows that inheritance of regular
> classes follows this rule of subtyping: class B is a subtype of class
> A if B extends A.
>  This rule does not apply to generic types:
>
> ```
> List<B> lb = new ArrayList<>(); 
> List<A> la = lb;   // compile-time error
> ```

In your example, `Task<EntityA>`(as `B`) is a subtype of `Task<? extends ScannableEntity>`(as `A`),but `List<Task<EntityA>>`(as `List<B>`) is not a subtype of `List<Task<? extends ScannableEnity>>`(as `List<A>`).